# combining mysql statement into 3 columns not 3 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, I need to return one row with 3 columns not 1 column with 3 rows

```
select count(*) from p_a a
inner join p_aa aa on a.ID = aa.AlbumID 
where a.ID = '04c9ed6e-1fb2-4d49-b5f6-a9d227ad7e7d'
union 
select count(*) from _ph p 
inner join pa a on a.ID = p.AlbumID
where a.ID = '04c9ed6e-1fb2-4d49-b5f6-a9d227ad7e7d'
union
Select LastUpdate from tsimestamp ats where ats.AlbumID = '04c9ed6e-1fb2-4d49-b5f6-a9d227ad7e7d';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
select (select count(*) from p_a a inner join p_aa aa on a.ID = aa.AlbumID where a.ID = '04c9ed6e-1fb2-4d49-b5f6-a9d227ad7e7d'),
       (select count(*) from _ph p inner join pa a on a.ID = p.AlbumID where a.ID = '04c9ed6e-1fb2-4d49-b5f6-a9d227ad7e7d'),
       (select LastUpdate from tsimestamp ats where ats.AlbumID = '04c9ed6e-1fb2-4d49-b5f6-a9d227ad7e7d');
```

Comment: Thank you, I was forgetting the commas. Thanks!!